# Claims Based Authenticaion in 2010: Change UserAttributes

Tags: development, claims-based-auth

I have a custom claims provider which adds some claims from an external system (eg. Email, Fullname, etc.).
This works fine, but i want to display the value from the fullname-claim on the top-right corner and not the name from the AD. Is there a way to set this name in the Provider or elsewhere?

Also i want to view the claims on the user information page if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i sort of figured it out. There are two ways:

1. Write a HttpModule which gets the data from the claims or the external system and updates the current user (ugly)
2. Create an external content type with a GetItem-Operation and configure a new User Profile Synchronization Connection which uses this BDC. (See References)

References:

- http://www.codefornuts.com/2010/09/importing-user-profile-attributes-from.html
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2011/02/06/sharepoint-2010-user-profiles-service-part-3-adding-wcf-bcs-model.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/momalek/archive/2011/02/06/sharepoint-2010-user-profile-service-part-4-configure-ups-synchronization-sources.aspx